# DateTime field with microsecond precision in Flask Admin

Tags: python, datetime, flask, flask-admin

I have a `sqlalchemy.DateTime` field in my model. In the admin page, if I open the edit page for a particular instance and I click save without changing anything, it will in fact remove the microseconds precision of the field.

Before saving: `2017-11-16 12:33:07.261537`
After saving: `2017-11-16 12:33:07`

How can I make the form keep the microseconds precision?

Comment: You could use another more precise [data type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#generic-types) like [Numeric](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric) or maybe [Time](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Time). You'd have to transform it going in and coming out of the database.